# How to Uninstall RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubymine

How do you uninstall RubyMine (from Mac OSX or other systems)?

It doesn't come with an uninstaller (from what I can tell). There are no options to uninstall in the application itself. [There is no documentation (except a "Thank you for trying to uninstall..." on their site.](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/uninstall/index.html)

I can drag the App to the trash, but I assume there are Preferences, etc. to also uninstall. I hate to lose files.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/uninstall.html

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to delete the following directories:

- ~/Library/Caches/RubyMine*
- ~/Library/Application\ Support/RubyMine*
- ~/Library/Preferences/RubyMine*
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.rubymine.plist*
- ~/Library/Logs/RubyMine*

Comment: Under ~/Library/Preferences/RubyMine* there's also a file that should be deleted (com.jetbrains.rubymine.plist)

Comment: `~/Library/Application Support/RubyMine*` need to be replaced with `~/Library/Application\ Support/RubyMine*` to escape the space between directory name for the command line use.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a one-liner that should delete all the files associated with RubyMine and print the files found and deleted to stdout.

```
find ~/Library -type d -iname '*rubymine*' -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to delete following files, more information for other platform [click here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)

```
Configuration:
```

~/Library/Preferences/PRODUCTVERSION

```
Caches:
```

~/Library/Caches/PRODUCTVERSION

```
Plugins:
```

~/Library/Application Support/PRODUCTVERSION

```
Logs:
```

~/Library/Logs/PRODUCTVERSION

PRODUCT would be one of the following:

```
IntelliJIdea (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition)
IdeaIC (IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition)
RubyMine
WebIde (WebStrom and PhpStorm use this common directory)
PyCharm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just drag the application to the trash. If you really want to get the preference files, look in `~/Library/Application Support` for a folder called "JetBrains" or "RubyMine", and look in `~/Library/Preferences` for the preferences file; it probably starts with "com.jetbrains" or has "jetbrains" or "rubymine" in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Mac OS applications are pretty well-behaved, and you can just get rid of the application bundle itself (preferences may actually be handy to keep around). If you'd like a general solution for getting rid of preference files automatically, try [AppTrap](http://onnati.net/apptrap/).